# You don't have permission to access /folder on this server - AWS EC2

Tags: php, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I know that there are a billion questions about that, but I cannot make it work.

What have I done so far :

1. Change my httd.conf file so that the DirectoryRoot is `/home/ec2-user/folder`.
2. Restarted my apache server.
3. `chmod -R 775 /home/ec2-user/folder`
4. Changed my httd.conf (only the changed lines are in here)

...

```
#
# DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
# documents. By default, all requests are taken from this directory, but
# symbolic links and aliases may be used to point to other locations.
#

#DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
DocumentRoot "/home/ec2-user/folder"


#
# Each directory to which Apache has access can be configured with respect
# to which services and features are allowed and/or disabled in that
# directory (and its subdirectories).
#
# First, we configure the "default" to be a very restrictive set of
# features.
#
<Directory />
#    Options FollowSymLinks
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
#    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and then this :

```
# This should be changed to whatever you set DocumentRoot to.
#

#<Directory "/var/www/html">
<Directory "/home/ec2-user/folder">
#
# Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
# or any combination of:
#   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
#
# Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
# doesn't give it to you.
#
# The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options
# for more information.
#
  #  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
#
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
    AllowOverride All

#
# Controls who can get stuff from this server.
#
    Order allow,deny
 #   Allow from all
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and then this :

```
#
# Listen: Allows you to bind Apache to specific IP addresses and/or
# ports, in addition to the default. See also the <VirtualHost>
# directive.
#
# Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to
# prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses (0.0.0.0)
#
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
#Listen 80
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
```

But I still have permission denied on /file.php.

What am I missing?

EDIT : I have also changed the DocumentRoot. Before that, I had a wrong url error, now I do not have the permissions. So, right now, the url is correct, I just haven't set the correct permissions for it.

Comment: What is APACHE_RUN_USER and APACHE_RUN_GROUP set as in your conf file also what is the user and group of the files in your DirectoryRoot.

Comment: Since your directory root already includes `folder`, the file should be accessible at `/file.php`, not `/folder/file.php`.

Comment: @DavidLevesque also tried that, same error again.

Comment: Note: `# This should be changed to whatever you set DocumentRoot to.` ... Did you also set DocumentRoot?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot yes, I did, sorry forgot to paste that one. Inside the same file. Before doing that it said url not found, now it says I do not have persmission. So, it is a matter of permissions as I see it - and not a wrong url

Comment: How about checking the log files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't do something different from the above - but after restarting my Apache and exiting my AWS a number of times - then it magically worked.  By following the above steps and checking the logs for errors, you should have it fixed.